# laptop sporadically displays: limited connectivity

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, router, connection

I have a Dell inspiron laptop about 18 months old running Windows 7.  I have had a problem sporadically for the last 2 months.

I will be using the internet when all of the sudden my browser can't open any web pages.  Then I see the icon in the system tray that says limited or no connectivity, despite the signal being perfect and there aren't any other routers in the immediate vicinity to interfere.  When I try to run the windows Troubleshooter it says I am connected to the network but that the router cannot access the internet.  However, if I disconnect from the connection and reconnect, the connection works fine.

This happens every hour, or sometimes even every 5-10 minutes. and I just disconnect and reconnect and it works fine.

Also, I have several other devices that continue to work while my laptop displays limited or no connectivity.

I don't think it is a firewall issue (I use AVG Free and Windows Firewall).

I found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/111074/windows-7-wireless-signal-good-internet-often-says-limited-or-no-activity) which suggests setting up a continuous ping to the default gateway.  When I do this, the pings return fine until I get the Limited connectivity icon at which point it states "request timed out".

I am pretty sure it doesn't have anything to do with IP conflicts either.

How can I troubleshoot this problem?  Any suggestions?

Comment: Try restarting the computer and wireless card. Delete all WiFi connection profiles. Test it out.

Comment: Good advice.  I just did that.  I will see how it works in the next couple hours.

Comment: Any chance you're on an Intel networking card? I've heard of (and experienced) errors like this on them.

Comment: Yes it is an Intel Centrino Advanced N 6230.

Comment: @HelpingHand That didn't solve it.  I am still having the problem.

Comment: Well, I don't really have any other clues to it. I searched up your problem in Google and got this: [This](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/windowsnetworking/ht/limited-connect.htm). Not sure if you have read it already, but it might fix your problem. Take a look at all of your networking settings (WiFi card, DNS, and so on...) and just make sure that it is all configured correctly.

Comment: I am pretty sure that your problem is a software issue.

Answer (score 0):

There may be loose or disconnected antenna wires on the wireless card. I had this issue where one wire was disconnected. These are like little snaps that press onto a small nub.

Not knowing your exact model it should look something like this when you open the access panel.

[image: wifi card]

Comment: Not sure that he should attempt this until he's positive that its not software.

Comment: @HelpingHand - It is just an access panel and would at least eliminate the issue of being a physical connection issue. Like I said, I did have this problem and it was one antenna wire disconnected.

Comment: Is it possible, yes. Is it SOMETIMES hard to get to, YES! I'd use that as a last resort unless you can access it easily depending on your computer model and type.